# Making Int64 the default integer dtype instead of standard int64 in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like all my dataframes, regardless of whether they're built up from any one of the constructor overloads, whether they're derived from `.read_csv()`, `.read_xlsx()`, `.read_sql()`, or any other method, to use the new nullable [**`Int64`** datatype](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support) as the default `dtype` for all integers, rather than `int64`.

I'm willing to go to literally any level of insanity to do this if there isn't a 'nice' way, including subclassing the DataFrame or Series classes, and reimplementing any number of methods and constructor attributes, etc.

My question is, **can this be done?** If so, **how would I go about it?**

Comment: "I'm willing to go to literally any level of insanity to do this" At that point, anything is possible.

Comment: It's not that simple (obviously) but can't you just write a couple of lines to convert whatever int columns you may have to nullable?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a function like this:

```py
def nan_ints(df, convert_strings=False, subset=None):
    types = ["int64", "float64"]
    if subset is None:
        subset = list(df)
    if convert_strings:
        types.append("object")
    for col in subset:
        if df[col].dtype in types:
            df[col] = (
                df[col].astype(float, errors="ignore").astype("Int64", errors="ignore")
            )
    return df
```

It iterates through each column and coverts it to an Int64 if it is a int. If it's a float it will convert to a Int64 only if all of the values in the column could be converted to ints other than the NaN's.  I've given you the option to convert strings to Int64 as well with the **convert_strings** argument.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,2,3,1],
                  'b':[1,2,3,np.nan],
                  'c':['1','2','3',np.nan],
                  'd':[3,2,1,np.nan]})


nan_ints(df1,convert_strings=True,subset=['b','c'])
df1.info()
```

Will return the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
a    4 non-null float64
b    3 non-null Int64
c    3 non-null Int64
d    3 non-null float64
dtypes: Int64(2), float64(2)
memory usage: 216.0 bytes
```

if you are going to use this on every DataFrame you could add the function to a module and import it every time you want to use pandas.
`from my_module import nan_ints`
Then just use it with something like:
`nan_ints(pd.read_csv(path))`

**Note:** Nullable integer data type is New in version 0.24.0.
Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: This truncates floats which is maybe undesired (I would think usually undesired)...

Comment: It's only going to truncate the float column if all the floats in the column are whole numbers.  Seems low risk to me....I suppose we could add in an optional argument to accept a list of columns to convert. @Any Hayden Should I make that edit?

Comment: @AndyHayden I added the column as requested. MatthewGdV am I on the right track here or were you wanting something else entirely?

Comment: I started the bounty because I was hoping for a way to monkey patch pandas to use Int64 automatically for integer columns, but for the meantime I've written code similar to this to convert columns to Int64.

Comment: Why do you call `.astype(float)` before `.astype('Int64')`?

Comment: If you do want to convert objects to IntegerDtype you will have to covert it to a float first, or you will get the error: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

Comment: You can get rid of your try block with the `errors='ignore'` option of astype. It'll just return the original object if it fails to cast, which is the same behavior as what you have.

Comment: @Jon  I'm not sure that it makes the code more readable, but I did go ahead and edit the code to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would put my money on monkey patching. The easiest way would be to monkey patch the DataFrame constructor. That should go something like this:

```
import pandas
pandas.DataFrame.__old__init__ = pandas.DataFrame.__init__
def new_init(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype(), copy=False):
    self.__old__init__(data=data, index=index, columns=None, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

pandas.DataFrame.__init__ = new_init
```

Of course, you run the risk of breaking the world. Good luck!

Comment: The `pd.DataFrame` constructor infers `dtype` for each column if it is not specified. This solution would force all callers to pass `dtype=None` explicitly to simulate that behavior, which would likely break many build-in functions in the library.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant about breaking the world. It's sort of a try it and see solution. It will depend on how they use the library. If all the data they work with is integer data, it might work.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to monkey patch pandas, but my columns are a mixture of different types so I would need something more sophisticated than this.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I don't know of a way to patch without getting into pandas' machinery. I bet you could patch at a deeper level, but that would require quite a bit of sleuthing and probably would rely on internal API's.